# Variable scope and source command in Tcl

Tags: variables, tcl, scope

I have the following two files:
a.tcl:

```
set condition false
source b.tcl
```

b.tcl:

```
if {$condition} {
    puts "hello"
}
```

When I run a.tcl, it prints "hello". Is this a correct practice for accessing variable defined in a.tcl? What is the scope of $condition in b.tcl? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of `condition` is global.  The `source` command evaluates the script read from the specified file in the context it's run; in your case this context is also global, hence your `puts` works.

The question about practice is more complicated as it hightly depends on what you actually do.

Answer (score 1):

The way the `source` command works is pretty much exactly as if it was reading the file into a string and then passing that to `eval` (the sole subtlety is to do with `info script`). That means that the scope that the `source` was done in will be the one that the outermost level of the script is evaluated in, and so that you could have `condition` be a local variable there:

```
proc funkystuff {condition} {
    source b.tcl
}
funkystuff true
```

That will work (and is in fact vital for how Tcl's package definition scripts work; they're evaluated in a context where there is a local variable `$dir` that describes where the package definition is located) but it can most certainly lead to code that is confusing!
Because of this, it's good practice to write your scripts so that the code inside them makes no assumptions about what context it is evaluated in. The easiest way to do that is often to put the code in the script inside a namespace, where the name of the namespace is fully qualified.

```
namespace eval ::foobar {
    # Do stuff here...
}
```

It's also a good thing to try to write code that isn't excessively parameterized on sourcing, instead saving that for either which version of the code you load (e.g., one file for Linux, another for Windows) or what parameters you pass to the commands. Of course you don't *have* to work that way, but it does help make your code robust and easy to understand.

Finally, the scope used for the main script to a Tcl interpreter is always evaluated at the global level (i.e., in the `::` namespace with no parent scope).